# how to add {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}} for transaction email tempalte

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, email-templates

i am creating the custom module and i need to send status update email to customer. i am getting the template data but not able able to process the template.

```
$customemailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->load($storetemplate);                  

            //$orderdata=$this->object_to_array($order);
            $customemailTemplate->getTemplateFilter();
            $orderarray=array();
  $orderarray['increment_id']=$order->getIncrementId();
  $orderarray['customer_name']=$order->getCustomerName();

$processedTemplate = $customemailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($orderarray);

echo $processedTemplate;
```

any hep will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong! there is no need to create variable just pass the order data and you are done! so i edit your code sample, so your code will be as follow.

```
<?php
        $customemailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                ->load($storetemplate);                  

                $orderarray=array();
      $orderarray['order']=$order;

    $processedTemplate = $customemailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($orderarray);
?>
```